# URL Redirect for very specific URL

Tags: .htaccess

I'm looking to create a `.htaccess` URL redirect for a specific URL.

```
Redirect /photography/index.php https://www.example.com/photography-services/
```

but the issue is, I need URL patterns like:

```
https://www.example.com/photography/index.php?view=findphotos
```

to still work.

Basically, any `index.php` URL with a variable to still go to the page, but anyone trying to attempt to reach the landing page directly would get redirected to a new page. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible...

In other words, you only want the specific URL `/photography/index.php` (without a query string) to redirect to `/photography-services/`.

You need to use mod_rewrite to check for an empty query string.

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file in the document root.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^photography/index\.php$ /photography-services/ [R=302,L]
```

If you have existing mod_alias `Redirect` (or `RedirectMatch`) directives then you may need to also convert these to mod_rewrite, if there is a conflict.

Note that the above is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change it to 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed that it works OK (to avoid caching issues).

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: One minor edit required:  RewriteRule ^photography/index\.php$ /photography-services/ [R=302,L] --> RewriteRule ^/photography/index\.php$ /photography-services/ [R=302,L]

Comment: But that "minor edit" won't work in .htaccess? The URL-path that the RewriteRule matches against does not start with a slash in a directory context.

Comment: ... you would only require a slash prefix if this directive was in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context.